# Java Cipher.{getInstance,implInit} Too Slow

Tags: java, performance, cryptography

I just switched from using a custom DES to the builtin DES using the following:

```
    SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(key8, "DES");
    des = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
    des.init(opmode, sk);
```

and now I find that getInstance, implInit, chooseProvider and so on together literally talks *6 times* as long as doFinal.

100000 cycles of creating an instance and doing one encrypt is now much slower.

Is there a way to bypass all of the javax.crypto setup? Can I clone what's returned by getInstance or something?

Comment: Try `BouncyCastle`? Save the `Cipher` instance? Without anymore context it's hard to say much.

Comment: I'm using it in a webapp so I can't reuse the cipher without a lock which is not ideal. Can't use another provider because the whole point is to eliminate deps. Is there no more direct way to get a new instance of DES. This seems stupid to me that just the infrastructure for getting a Cipher is so slow.

Comment: Cache preinitialized Cipher in ThreadLocal.

Comment: Ok. Using ThreadLocal is possible. Albeit disappointing.

Comment: Use an Object Pool of Ciphers.

Comment: The first access is always very slow because of classloading etc. Later accesses are much faster, however, using `ThreadLocal` may still make sense.

Comment: No. I ran 100000 cycles of getInstance, init, doFinal and it was getInstance was literally 6 times longer than everything else. It's finding a provider and touching disk files and verifying jars and such. There should be a way to get a handle to something that has already done all of that so that you can then just create new instances quickly.

Comment: Why not just line up the stuff you want to encrypt / decrypt and use multiple updates and one final operation? It's ECB, so the blocks are handled independently anyway. That way you also save some time for the subkey derivation in the `init` function. Upvoted because yeah, that time seems excessive. Note that it *does* depend on the providers you have installed, e.g. BC can take a long time to instantiate. Furthermore, you don't want to speed test with a debugger attached.